# only using mapboxGL library, attribution required?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

If I use mapboxGL library, without using any Mapbox basemap or data (I guess is possible to add as basemap my own WMS), do I have to keep the Mapbox watermark?

I had to read a few times, but I understand from the [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/attribution/) that the answer is NO, I don't have to keep the watermark.

Just to make sure :.)

Comment: In fact, if you use only your own map tiles the Mapbox lib _automatically_ removes its logo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. You don't need to provide any attribution if you're not using Mapbox data or designs.

From the linked doc:

> If your map does not use Mapbox designs, data, hosting, or other Mapbox APIs, Mapbox does not require you to provide attribution in either form.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a serious project, and you need advice on licensing, I'd consult with a lawyer. They can accurately tell you what kinds of attribution and licensing you need. Additionally this will protect you as you build your own ToS.